# Which is the class for kendo grid row invalid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to add some Invalid/Error class on Kendo grid row in some condition.

Means the class which can show red border on kendo grid row.

But i don't know the appropriate kendo class for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class: `k-state-error` (red border) or `k-invalid` dependant on your needs.

You can see this here: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/validator/index.html